# mask credit card cvv number

Tags: jsf, el, jsf-1.2

I use jsf 1.1 and adf. I wanted to write *** instead of credit card cvv info. If cvv info's length is 4, it will display ****, if cvv info's length is 3, it will display ***. I tried the code below but it didn't work. How can I do this in front end.
Thanks

```
value="#{if(bean.cvvNo.length ==3) '***': '****'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
value="#{bean.ccvNo.length == 3 ? '***' : '****'}"
```

Comment: could you post your backingBean?